# Excel VBA pop up to stop code from executing

Tags: excel, vba, popup

I have a file that starts updating data etc right when it is opened and then it is saved and closed. The file opens with a task scheduler daily.

My current key board does not have the break key so I cannot stop the code from executing manually. What I want to do is create a pop up that asks the user if it should stop, if the user then stops it they can work in the file but if the file opens automatically and the user is not present I need the file to close the popup after lets say 30 seconds then continue with the code.

Is this possible and how will I create a pop up and code like that

I have created a pop up but cannot get it to close and continue without the user input

Comment: Initial thoughts: use OnTime to schedule execution of your update code, then show a modless userform asking to cancel the scheduled action. In the scheduled update code, also close the form.  That way either the user cancels the update, and the form is closed, _or_ the scheduled action executes, which closes the form and does the update

Comment: "My current key board does not have the break key so I cannot stop the code from executing manually." - Does Ctrl-C not work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you another solution, if the user is present at any time he presses Shift to be asked if he wants to stop the process or not and depending on the answer the process will be stopped or continued. This can be done at any stage of the process (which I assume will be implemented inside a Loop)

```
'THIS CODE IN A MODULE 
'--------------------------------------------------
#If VB7 And Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

Private Const KEY_MASK As Integer = &HFF80

Public Function IsShiftKeyDown() As Boolean
   IsShiftKeyDown = CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyShift) And KEY_MASK )
End Function


'THIS CODE EMULATES THE DATA UPDATER
'-------------------------------------------------
Sub data_updater()
   Do
      DoEvents   'Necessary
      If IsShiftKeyDown() Then
         If MsgBox("SELECT OK TO STOP UPDATES", vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "BREAK FROM USER") = vbOK Then
            GoTo STOP_BY_USER
         End If
      End If

      'execute your code here
      
   Loop
   Exit Sub
STOP_BY_USER:
   'if necessary, wtite here code to complete the user break
End Sub


'usage example
'---------------
Sub STARTER()
   Call data_updater
End Sub
```